# Change style onPress + Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I want to change the style of the entire app when a button is pressed. I thought I can do this with a `reducer`. So I created:

ReducerStyles:

```
const initialState = 
        {
            name: styleNormal,
            path: './styles/styleNormal'
        }


export default function reducer01 (state = initialState, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case "changeStyleNormal":
             return [
                ...state,
                {
                name: name: action.payload,
                path: './styles/styleNormal'
                }
             ];

        case "changeStyleNew":
             return [
                ...state,
                {
                name: name: action.payload,
                path: './styles/styleNew'
                }
             ];

        default:
          return state
      }
    }
```

And Actions:

```
const CHANGE_STYLE_NORMAL = 'changeStyleNormal';
const CHANGE_STYLE_NEW = 'changeStyleNew';

export function changeStyleNormal(style){
    return {
        type: CHANGE_STYLE_NORMAL,
        payload: style
    }
}

export function changeStyleNew(style){
    return {
        type: CHANGE_STYLE_NEW,
        payload: style
    }
}
```

I created 2 styles in the `styles` folder so only 1 can be applied depending on the one selected/returned from the reducer. By default I have the `styleNormal` in the Reducer `initialState`. Imported the Actions, Reducer is combined and `mapStateToProps`:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
      style: state.style
  }
}


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    changeStyleNormal: (style) => {
      dispatch(changeStyleNormal(style));
    },
    changeStyleNew: (style) => {
      dispatch(changeStyleNew(style));
    }
  }
}
```

Added 2 buttons:

```
    <TouchableOpacity 
      style={styles.clickMe}
      onPress={()=>this.props.changeStyleNew('styleNew')}>
      <Text style={styles.black18}>New Style</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>


    <TouchableOpacity 
      style={styles.clickMe}
      onPress={()=>this.props.changeStyleNormal('styleNormal')}>
      <Text style={styles.black18}>Normal Style</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Now when the component is called,

```
render() {
 console.log("style: ",this.props.style);
```

This gives the style as:

[image]

I cannot access `this.props.style` out of the `render()` so where would I set the var `style = this.props.style.path` ?

Also, when I click any button, the actions are fine, but the styles are getting appended to the reducer:

[image]

I want only the one passed to be in the reducer. So I can use it to set the style.

Is this the proper way to do it? Please help.

Many thanks.

**UPDATE 1:**

```
class Ext2 extends Component {

//console.log('Style:', this.props.people);  // <= This throws an internal server error 500
// const styles = this.props.style.path;  // same error as above

    render() {
     console.log("style: ",this.props.style);   //<= Works
     console.log("stylePath: ",this.props.style.path)  //<= Works
```

Comment: may not be relevant but your initial state is an object yet you return an array from the reducer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot access this.props.style out of the render()

what makes you think you can't access it? you can access `this.props` from anywhere in the `class`.

> Also, when I click any button, the actions are fine, but the styles
>   are getting appended to the reducer

Your initial state is an object yet you are returning an array from your reducers:

```
case "changeStyleNew":
             return [
                ...state,
                {
                name: name: action.payload,
                path: './styles/styleNew'
                }
             ];
```

Instead try returning an object like this:

```
case "changeStyleNew":
             return{
                ...state,
                name: name: action.payload,
                path: './styles/styleNew'
              }
```

**EDIT**
As a followup to your comment, here is a simple example of how and where you could access `this.props` outside the `render` method:

```js
class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: this.props.count // acess props
    };

    this.add = this.add.bind(this);
    this.sub = this.sub.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({ count: nextProps.count });
  }

  add() {
    this.props.addClick(); // acess props
  }

  sub() {
    this.props.subClick(); // acess props
  }

  render() {
    const { count } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Count:{count} </div>
        <button onClick={this.add}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.sub}>-</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };

    this.addClick = this.addClick.bind(this);
    this.subClick = this.subClick.bind(this);
  }

  addClick() {
    const nextstate = this.state.count + 1;
    this.setState({ count: nextstate });
  }

  subClick() {
    const nextstate = this.state.count - 1;
    this.setState({ count: nextstate });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Wellcome to my Counter!</h2>
        <Counter
          count={this.state.count}
          addClick={this.addClick}
          subClick={this.subClick}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Reducer works like a charm! It resolved the first question. Thanks. Please check `Update1` in the question for the issue with defining `styles`. How would I set the path for the variable `styles`?

Comment: thanks mate .. it worked .. I was able to access it within the render itself. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Somename i've added a snippet.